Problema con el Tercer Fargment
Muy buenas comunidad, he aquí molestando, les comento que quiero realizar lo siguiente que limpiar todos los fragment desde el primero hasta el último, en resumen poseo cuatro fragment y el modo que quiero hacerlo es con el EvebtBus, por lo cual en el botón del primer fragment del limpiar hago el traspaso de datos de esta manera:
private void Limpiardatos (){
    limpiarDatos1 = true;
    // Transacción para el segundo fragmento (manoFragment)
    mano manoFragment = new mano();
    Bundle argsMano = new Bundle();
    argsMano.putBoolean("limpiarDatos1", limpiarDatos1);
    manoFragment.setArguments(argsMano);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction1.replace(R.id.segundo, manoFragment);
    transaction1.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction1.commit();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new LimpiarDatosEvent(limpiarDatos1));

    // Transacción para el tercer fragmento (repuestosFragment)
    repuestos repuestosFragment = new repuestos();
    Bundle argsRepuestos = new Bundle();
    argsRepuestos.putBoolean("limpiarDatos1", limpiarDatos1);
    repuestosFragment.setArguments(argsRepuestos);
    FragmentTransaction transaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction2.replace(R.id.tercero, repuestosFragment, "terceros"); // Usar un tag para identificar el fragmento
    transaction2.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction2.commit();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new LimpiarDatosEvent(limpiarDatos1));
    txtpresupuesto1.setText("");
    txtnombre4.setText("");
    txtrut4.setText("");
    txtfecha1.setText("");
    txtnombre5.setText("");
    txtsiniestro.setText("");
    txtnombre6.setText("");
    txtfono4.setText("");
    txttercero.setText("");
    txtfonotercero.setText("");
    txtmarca2.setText("");
    txtmodelo1.setText("");
    txtano.setText("");
    txtpatente.setText("");
    txtchasis.setText("");
    a.setText("");
    b.setText("");
    c.setText("");
    d.setText("");
    e.setText("");
    f.setText("");
    tbldatos1.removeAllViews();
    sppatente.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion4 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion4.add("Seleccione patente");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador4 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion4);
    sppatente.setAdapter(adaptador4);
    spcompania.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion.add("Seleccione Cliente");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion);
    spcompania.setAdapter(adaptador);
    spliquidador.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion1 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion1.add("Seleccione Liquidador");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador1 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion1);
    spliquidador.setAdapter(adaptador1);
    spmarca.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion2 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion2.add("Seleccione Marca");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion2);
    spmarca.setAdapter(adaptador2);
    spmodelo.setAdapter(null);
    ArrayList<String> seleccion3 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion3.add("Seleccione Modelo");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador3 = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion3);
    spmodelo.setAdapter(adaptador3);
    shouldLoadSpinner1 = false;
    btn_modificar.setEnabled(false);
    btn_eliminar.setEnabled(false);
    btn_grabar.setEnabled(true);
    llenarSpinner();
}

@Subscribe
public void onLimpiarDatosEvent(LimpiarDatosEvent event) {

}

en el traspaso del segundo fragmento ningún problema lo realiza bien y el proceso de limpiar el segundo fragment nada de nada cero problemas, una vez que termina de hacer el proceso debe dirigirse al tercer fragment, y es a{i en donde me indica los errores:
Process: com.example.gestion, PID: 26996
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0802cc (com.example.gestion:id/tercero) for fragment repuestos{ca0a593} (57e878b5-3de1-4ee3-80e0-532e1612c484 id=0x7f0802cc tag=terceros)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:547)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1839)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26996 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:54781', transport: 'socket'

por el error me informa que no existe el id del tercero, por lo cual les presento el xml del tercer fragment:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tercero"
android:tag="@+tag/terceros"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".archivos.repuestos">

si se dan cuenta existe el id llamado tercero, por lo cual debería realizar el llamado y traspaso como corresponde, favor de ayudarme ya llevo varios días en esto y no puedo salir de esto, y desde ya muchas gracias.
